# When long dividing decimals 26/2.5 in 2:40-3:30 of this video why do we continue calculating for the quotient instead of stopping at 10 r10?

Tags: arithmetic

Now we have a remainder that isnt 0 or over the divisor, why dont we put r10 to the end of the quotient and be done??wHY IS 10 R10 WRONG? No, we add a trailing zero and it leaves us winding up at 10.4, which I know IS right. But WHY don’t we stop when we have 10 r10 at 2:40 in this video. And on a test why’s this wrong?

VIDEO (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PU5JshO0xA&index=7&list=PL45A96B834415F332Since)

Comment: An integer and remainder is technically correct. If you're asked to calculate $10\over3$, and write 3 remainder 1, that's equivalent to telling us $10=3\times3+1$. But, that's sort of like writing $\sqrt{9}$ as the answer to 'find the square root of 9' - the marking scheme for a test will probably want you to simplify the answer as much as possible. Similarly, writing the answer as integer and remainder isn't a form we'd call simplified as it just tells us $\frac{a}{b}=bd+r$, and so you should go for exact answers.

Comment: How do we know when wehave exact answers compared to a answer like 10 r10? i though it was ok to hve remainders.. how do we just pick n choose when we make our answer into a decimal?

Comment: Generally - answers with remainder are for when you're beginning to learn to do division, and that is what initially is taught in schools. But as you go further with the subject, these answers are no longer useful and you're required to give the answer in decimal or fractional form (you'll find that outside of tests, you'll be after these more when you're making calculations in general).

Comment: How do we know when we have to find exact answers compared to a answer like 10 r10? i thought it was ok to have remainders in the answer(which it's not here).. how do we know for sure when to add that trailing zero and not add r10 to the end of the problem but continue solving the problem?

Comment: In general - don't leave remainders in answers as it's actually not ok. The only time you leave remainders is when the questions says it's ok to do so.

Comment: Ohh so with all remainders i can keep soving the problem and find the decimal form of the answer instead of putting remainder x?

Comment: Yes. I haven't watched the video, so it might've already told you, but there are cases where you can have repeating decimals, and so you stop at that point once you realise that. You would then have a recurring decimal as your answer.

Comment: oh ok, i was just confused on why we added a trailing zero and continued solving the problem even after we had a remainder to put at the end of the answer thanks! im gonna rewatch the vid and learn how to thouroughly divide decimals.

Comment: one more time. so the gist is anytime we ave a remainder thats greater than zero we keep on solving the problem by adding trailing zeroes to the dividend so we can bring down those zeroes to the remainder so we can divide our divisor by or remainder and find the exact answer, but we stop once we know we hit repeating decimals.. is this conclusion right and does this apply with the majority division problems involving decimals?

Comment: I'd advise asking a separate question about long division if you have problems understanding it - I don't quite see what you mean by 'adding trailing zeroes' because I don't think that's what you do

Comment: watch 2:30-330 of the vid please

Comment: basically we do not keep remainders greater than zero and add that remainder to our answer. Instead we compute remainders and figure out the next step in the equation until we have a remainder of zero?

Comment: Ah I see what you meant by 'trailing zeroes'. Yes because $10=10.00000000000...$ for example.

Comment: shuri i see yur into coding as well, i see your into coding as well you should join my group https://www.facebook.com/groups/w3develops/

Answer (score 0):

The original problem was to solve
$\begin{array}{rlcc}
   2.5\overline{)26}
\end{array}$,
which got changed to solving
$\begin{array}{rlcc}
   25\overline{)260}
\end{array}$.

$10\; R\; 10$ conveys the information that $260 = 10 \times 25 + 10$.

But it would take some work to find that $26 = 10 \times 2.5 + 1$; that is, the answer to the original problem is $10 \; R \; 1$.

The bigger problem is that $10\; R\; 10$ and $10\; R\; 1$ are not **numbers**.

The notation $\begin{array}{rlcc}
   2.5\overline{)26}
\end{array}$
provides a framework in which that value of the fraction $\dfrac{26}{2.5}$ can be converted into an improper fraction. The equivalent problem,
 $\begin{array}{rlcc}
   25\overline{)260}
\end{array}$,
and its solution, tells us that 
$\dfrac{26}{2.5} = \dfrac{260}{25} = 10\dfrac{10}{25}$; which is much more useful.